# iOS How can I set constraints to fit device screen?

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder, constraints, xib

I want to set to fit device screenSize.

So, I added constraints.

- ToolBar Contraints

  Top Space to SuperView
  Leading Space to SuperView
  Trailing Space to Supervier
  Height Equals 44
- imageView Constraints

  Top Space to: Toolbar
  Leading Space to SuperView
  Trailing Space to superView
  Bottom Space to SuperView

[image: My constraints]

But, Result is this. Not Center! Not fit to device screen!
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the constants to zero. Judging by your screen shot the constants are of significant value. Set the constant value for the four constraints to the imageView (top, bottom, leading and trailing) to equal zero then update the frames.

*Note that no width, height or centering is required as auto layout has enough info to calculate the size and position.*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Set Height and width and set constraint